# ligação SQL a bd na rede

Tags: c#, sql-server, connectionstring

Desenvolvi uma aplicação em C# que usa o SQL Express que inicialmente a bd e a aplicação estavam instaladas numa só maquina.
O cliente agora necessita que a bd esteja disponivel apartir de outro computador na rede.
Instalei o SQL express na "outra" maquina e alterei a connection string para :

```
connectionString = "Data Source = 192.168.1.xx\SQLExpress,1433; Integrated Security=SSPI; Initial Catalog = baseDados;"/>
```

onde 192.168.1.xx é o IP da maquina onde está a base de dados localizada.
O Tcp/Ip está enabled.

Isto é o suficiente para conseguir fazer a conexão ?
Ao tentar aceder ao programa/base de dados dá o erro :
"...provider: TCP provider, error 0 - Uma tentativa de ligação falhou porque o componente ligado não respondeu correctamente após um período de tempo, o a ligação estabelecida falhou porque o anfitrião ligado não responder"
Alguém me pode dar uma ajuda?

Comment: Verificou o firewall? Por padrão algumas versões do SQL vêm com o protocolo TCP desabilitado.

Comment: sim, também desabilitei a firewall nos dois computadores..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifique nas propriedades do banco de dados se a seguinte opção está marcada:

[image: Server Properties]

No seu lugar, não usaria autenticação integrada. Ainda assim, se quiser usar, verifique se o usuário do IIS tem permissão no banco de dados:

[image: Login IIS]
[image: Login IIS - 2]

Ainda assim, se nada funcionar, use um usuário regular com uma senha. A autenticação integrada normalmente só funciona para estes casos bem se o banco de dados estiver integrado a um domínio.

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta. Confirmei todos os passos e estão todos como  me descreveu e mostra nas imagens. Continua sem resolver.

Comment: Neste caso seria interessante usar um usuário com senha mesmo. Experimente conectar neste banco de dados usando usuário e senha dentro do Microsoft SQL Management Studio.

Comment: Utilizando a mesma connectionString(tirando a Integrated Security=SSPI) e apenas mudando o server authentication, usando user e password, funcionou... Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

O endereço ip 192.168.x.x é um endereço de IP interno, o que você quer é o endereço de IP externo do outro computador.

Se se tratar de uma máquina Windows pode o descobrir utilizando o comando ipconfig na máquina de destino.

Comment: Mas eu no computador 2(o que nao tem a bd) tenho de por na connection string o ip da maquina que tem a bd, certo? E fazendo o ipconfig na outra maquina, qual o ip que necessito? o ipV4 address?

Comment: Exactamente. Caso esteja a utilizar ipv6 então será ipv6, no entanto é mais provável ser ipv4. Caso continue a não funcionar deve ter alguma configuração incorrecta.